# PhoneGap EmailComposer issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to phoneGap, I want to add a email button - so I've tried to install the EmailComposer Plugin. When I try to compile in xcode I get the following error :
'PGPlugin.h' file not found.
I've a fresh install of Phonegap 1.9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of the plugin?? Phonegap plugin now uses `CDVPlugin.h` and you can confirm that by checking the source of the plugin.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/EmailComposer

Update you plugin code if it is older and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, found the problem, yes its was the wrong version. Strangely the GIT repo has both iPhone and IOS folders with EmailComposer plugins. I used the iPhone one by mistake. I'm guessing that its for older version of the iphone?

Thanks